# Python server exposing both and xml and json rpc interface

Tags: python, xml-rpc, rpc, json-rpc

As the title says, is there a way to expose a function to both the JSON-RPC and the XML-RPC interface? Preferably one server running on a single port would answer to both types of requests.

Thanks!

Comment: Cant you just read the http content type header, and return the appropriate answer depending on that.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a library that supports that out-of-the-box. The libraries I've seen just register the functions and start a server on a designated port, but they are dependent on a specific protocol.

Comment: the easises way to get started would be to use something simple like flask or bottle, and then as suggested bellow read the request for the content type header and aply a serializer to turn your answer into the right format

Answer (score -1):

One of the usual ways of returning different formats is to specify the type you want in the url in some way. Most common are:

```
http://example.com/some/page.<format>
```

or

```
http://example.com/some/page?output=<format>
```

And then your returned object should be transformed into the wanted format:

```
// somewhere at the end of the method handling the request
return Formater(format_param).format(response_object)
```

Comment: even better would be to use the HTTP header content-type to request the wanted format